# Is there a way to get the enum type from and ordinal value?

Tags: java

What i mean by  that is suppose

```
Enum xyzType {

    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
```

I know I can get the ordinal a value of C, by doing   xyzType.C.ordinal() which is 2.
Suppose I just have 2, I would to get the enum type C.  I can't seem to find anything in the enum API that would do this.   I would prefer not to have a huge switch statement to compare each ordinal value and return the enum.   Is there a better to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean the enum type, which is `xyzType`, or the enum instance `C` of type `xyzType`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest approach is:

```
xyzType xyz = xyzType.values()[ordinalValue];
```

However, this will create a new array each time. An alternative would be to cache it within the enum:

```
public enum Xyz {
    Foo, Bar;

    private static final Xyz[] VALUES = values();

    public Xyz fromOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        return VALUES[ordinal];
    }
}
```